# Cytoscape.js mapData mapper returning same color for all vertices

Tags: javascript, css, cytoscape.js, mappers

I am trying to use the Cytoscape.js mapData() mapper to produce a color gradient between red and blue for my vertice's background color.  I am using the exact example from the documentation:

```
'background-color': 'mapData(degree, 1, 100, blue, red)'
```

However it sets all of the nodes to the color blue.  The degrees vary in the data and I know that the cytoscape 'data(degree)' mapper works for setting the node size.  Any direction or advice on this would be very helpful. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem too and it came down to having single quotes around the data value e.g.

`{ data: { id: 'PC_32_3', qvalue : 0.72262394042574 }, classes : 'insignificantDown9' },`

was interpreted correctly but

```
{ data: { id: 'PC_32_3', qvalue : '0.72262394042574' }, classes : 'insignificantDown9' },
```

was not. Presumably the string value is always cast to 0 which forces the mapping to one end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the data field, then the mapper has nothing to map from.  Degree is calculated metadata, it's not user data.

Comment: There is an attribute on my graph that is called 'degree', I am not using the degree property of cytoscape.js.  I have tried this with other numerical properties on my graph with the same result.  Is there anything else I could be missing?